# How can I register Alexa V2 Servlet in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, alexa-skills-kit

With Alexa, I want to call my Spring Boot application, which runs on a Google App Engine. I can send requests from the Alexa-Simulator and can log the request.

I followed this tutorial (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/implementing-an-alexa-skill-with-spring-boot-also-why-would-you-do-such-a-thing-9992c0797646) to register the SpeechletServlet to call my Intents.

Now, Im using the Alexa-SDK V2, but I don´t know how to register the servlet in this version.

```
@Configuration
```

public class AlexaConfig {

```
@Autowired
private HandlerSpeechlet handlerSpeechlet;

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean registerSpeechletServlet() {

    SpeechletServlet speechletServlet = new SpeechletServlet();
    speechletServlet.setSpeechlet(handlerSpeechlet);

    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(speechletServlet, "/alexa");
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

}

This is my current configuration for V1, but how can I do it in V2?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by following the instructions of the sample github project:

https://github.com/TheSilentHorizon/spring-boot-alexa

Just implement the AlexaConfiguration.java Class and configure the application.properties

Comment: Great - feel free to accept your own answer if you managed to solve your problem - that way other users can see that this problem already has a solution.